# Creating Simple Dropdown in MVC5 using asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create the following dropdown in asp.net

Week : (dropdown will have options 1,2,3 and 4)

How to create this is MVC5 using ASP.NET ?

(Dont mind using Bootstrap, but the dropdown should be a simple dropdown and not with bootstrap buttons or hyperlinks)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First off; do you base your dropdown on a model property, or should it be hardcoded?

If the former, you could use the `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper ([MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)).

If the latter, use the following ([W3 School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)):

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```